# Django Model.delete() not working in signal

Tags: python, django

I am trying to delete a model instance from within a signal callback

```
@receiver(m2m_changed)
def many_to_many_changed(sender, instance, action, **kwargs):
    if action == "post_remove":
        if not instance.invoices.all().exists():
            payment = Payment.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
            payment.delete()
            instance.delete()
```

This is my code but neither instance.delete() or payment.delete() deletes anything, I have also tried to put `Payment.objects.all().delete()` but nothing changed.

What could I try to do? Is it possible to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: What response are you getting?

Comment: You did not specify the m2m relation to be triggered in the `@receiver(...)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what do you mean?